# Webscraping a Javascript page using Selenium in python.. however unable to get page content and getting error

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on Webscraping of a URL https://data.cms.gov/tools/mapping-medicare-disparities-by-population using below code. I am unable to get the HTML code so that can traverse through the tags. I am using Chrome browser using Selenium in Python.

```
import time 
import pandas as pd 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.headless = True
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') 
chrome_path = ChromeDriverManager().install() 
chrome_service = Service(chrome_path) 

driver = Chrome(options=options, service=chrome_service) 

url = "https://data.cms.gov/tools/mapping-medicare-disparities-by-population" 

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(30)

siteContentWrapper1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "siteContentWrapper")
```

Above code gives error as below -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "CMS.py", line 30, in <module>
    siteContentWrapper1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "siteContentWrapper")

  File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1248, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {

  File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".siteContentWrapper"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=113.0.5672.127)
```

Comment: there is no such class as siteContentWrapper on the page. Maybe you want to use `ContentArea` ?

Comment: @VasiliyvvscodeVanchuk I want the content of the page https://data.cms.gov/tools/mapping-medicare-disparities-by-population

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its part on iframe you first have to switch to iframe before accessing the element
[image]
Like below

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
frame = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="population"]')))

driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Full code

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ExpectedConditions

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
chrome_service = Service(chrome_path)

driver = Chrome(options=options, service=chrome_service)

url = "https://data.cms.gov/tools/mapping-medicare-disparities-by-population"

driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 90)
frame = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="population"]')))

driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
siteContentWrapper1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "siteContentWrapper")))
print(siteContentWrapper1.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. However still getting below reply

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "CMS.py", line 34, in <module>
    siteContentWrapper1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "siteContentWrapper")))

  File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException

Comment: try updated code with increased timeout

Comment: I added 
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080") and also edited timeout to 60.. but still getting the same error. I will increase it to 120 and will try

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have modified the timeout and able to get the text now.